# Rank subsets of a dataset

Tags: r, rank

I'm new to R and have a relatively simple problem that I can't figure out. I have a dataset that is about 30,000 rows and 3 columns. Every 30 rows is one sample, but there is no identifiers for the samples. I want to Rank each of the rows for individual samples (i.e. I need to rank each subset of 30--1:30, then 31:60 then 61:90 and so forth to 30000). I'd like to cbind the output to the original data table. Any simple ways to accomplish this task? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To separate these rows, add another column:

```
dataset$rank <- rep(1:1000, each=30)
```

For anything more detailed, a bit of detail in the question would be in order.

Comment: +1 - though I wouldn't call that a "rank", more like an "id". I agree we need more detail as to what the OP calls "rank".

Comment: Thanks for your input. Here are additional details. I have a three column table mydataset. It is a dataset of 30,000 rows. However, every 30 rows, I change samples. I would like to rank the values (not order them) in column V3 for each sample mydataset$V3 and put that rank in a new column mydataset$V4.  This means I would like to perform the rank function on every set of 30 rows. I imagine as a forloop this would rank rows 1-30 exit the loop then perform the same function on the next 30 (rows 31-60). Is this enough information? What else would you like to know?

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```
n <- 3000
df <- data.frame(V1 = runif(n), V2 = runif(n), V3 = runif(n))
```

How to add a column that computes `rank` on `V3` every 30 rows:

```
df <- transform(df, rank = ave(V3, (seq_along(V3) - 1) %/% 30, FUN = rank))
```

You can also break it out a bit if it helps comprehension:

```
df <- within(df, {ID   = 1 + (seq_along(V3) - 1) %/% 30
                  rank = ave(V3, ID, FUN = rank)})
```

In this second suggestion, I switched from `transform` to `within` as the former does not allow defining variables (`rank`) in terms of other newly defined variables (`ID`).